# Finding an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, material-ui, jsx

I want to put a function that checks whether the cart is empty or filled and display output based on this logic.
if cart.line_items.length is not true then it should run the EmptyCart function.
note that the "line_items" is an array from the API response.
it should then loop over each item and display the item in a material-ui grid.
here is my .jsx code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Typography, Button, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import useStyles from './styles.js';

const Cart = ({ cart }) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
//this function checks whether the cart is empty or filled
    const isEmpty = !cart.line_items.length;

    const EmptyCart = () => (
        <Typography variant="subtitle1" > Your cart is Empty </Typography>
    );

    const filledCart = () => (
        <>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                {cart.line_items.map((item) => (
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={4} key={item.id} >
                        <div>{item.name}</div>
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
            <div className={classes.cardDetails}>
                <Typography variant="h4">
                    Subtotal: {cart.subtotal.formatted_wih_symbol}
                </Typography>
                <div >
                    <Button className={classes.emptyButton} size="large" type="button" variant="contained" color="secondary" > Empty Cart </Button>
                    <Button className={classes.checkoutButton} size="large" type="button" variant="contained" color="primary" >Checkout</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );

    return (
        <Container>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            <Typography className={classes.title}>Your Shopping Cart</Typography>
            {isEmpty ? <EmptyCart /> : <filledCart />}
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Cart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `cart.line_items` is null or undefined.

like the following:

```
const isEmpty = !cart.line_items || !cart.line_items.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional check for `undefined` by using the **optional chaining** in JS like so :-

`const isEmpty = !cart.line_items?.length;`